# GameObject rotate -180° while dragging

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation

For a 2D game, I have this piece of code :

```
Vector3 mousePos2 = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition);
mousePos2.z = Camera.main.nearClipPlane;
Vector3 cardPos = transform.position;
Vector2 direction = mousePos2 - cardPos;
Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);
float degreesPerSecond = 90.0f * Time.deltaTime;
transform.rotation = Quaternion.RotateTowards(transform.rotation, targetRotation, degreesPerSecond);
```

It rotate the Card toward the mouse while I drag it. Like [this](https://codepen.io/dstnation/pen/pyqGbN).
I have CardHolder with boxCollider2D and it work fine if I hover them.

However, once I hover the background (which don't have a collider) on the right, the Card rotate +180°(-180° if I'm on the left) on Y axis as if the mouse was far away on the Z plane.
It only happens if i'm not over a collider and on the gameboard, if I drag it outside the background (out of the limit of the game) Card rotate as expected.

I've tried :
- Change mousePos2.z to positive and zero.
- Add a collider to the background, it """work""" but a lot of things are messed up.
- Change all the Vector3 to Vector2, the problem is still the same.

Where does the problem come from and what could I do ?

Answer (score 0):

Solution found;

I had this :

```
private void OnMouseOver()
{
    if (!isOverCardHolder)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(target, transform.position.y);
    }
}
```

If the Card is not over a CardHolder, I set a new X position (To "pop-it" out of the cardDeck).

Thats why when dragging over the background, the Card X position was forcefully set by this OnMouseOver().

I replaced it by :

```
private void OnMouseEnter()
{
    if (!isOverCardHolder)
    {
        transform.position = new Vector2(target, transform.position.y);
    }
}
```

This way, it only fire once, and not if the Card is placed or dragged over nothing.